# Java WebStart unable to load resource in server

Tags: java, javafx, jar, classpath, java-web-start

I want to start my application with webstart, netbeans makes the "dist" folder and if I run the HTML from my computer the program works fine but if I upload the HTML, the JNLP, the JAR and the lib folder with all the jars libraries in my server the program throws an error, im guessing the jar tries to find the dependencies in the lib folder but there is a problem with a slash in the path because the server is running on linux, this is the error:

> ExitException[ 3]com.sun.deploy.net.FailedDownloadException: Unable to load resource: http://www.abaxomol.com/dist/lib\commons-io-2.4.jar

the problem is not in the JNLP because im declaring my resources like this in the resources tag :

```xml
<jar href="http://www.abaxomol.com/dist/lib/commons-io-2.4.jar" size="185140" download="eager" />
```

In the "project.properties" I found this

> ${file.reference.commons-io-2.4.jar}:\

and I think here is the problem but im not sure, any idea what is going on?

EDIT: full JNLP

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<jnlp spec="1.0" xmlns:jfx="http://javafx.com" href="ContenedoresChart.jnlp">
  <information>
    <title>ContenedoresChart</title>
    <vendor>Diego</vendor>
    <description>null</description>
    <offline-allowed/>
  </information>
  <resources>
    <j2se version="1.6+" href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se"/>
    <jar href="ContenedoresChart.jar" size="2200844" download="eager" />
    <jar href="http://www.abaxomol.com/dist/lib/commons-io-2.4.jar" size="198396" download="eager" />
    <jar href="http://www.abaxomol.com/dist/lib/guava-18.0.jar" size="2410298" download="eager" />
    <jar href="http://www.abaxomol.com/dist/lib/json-simple-1.1.1.jar" size="26301" download="eager" />
  </resources>
<security>
  <all-permissions/>
</security>
  <applet-desc  width="800" height="600" main-class="com.javafx.main.NoJavaFXFallback"  name="ContenedoresChart" >
    <param name="requiredFXVersion" value="8.0+"/>
  </applet-desc>
  <jfx:javafx-desc  width="800" height="600" main-class="contenedoreschart.ContenedoresChart"  name="ContenedoresChart" />
  <update check="always"/>
</jnlp>
```

Full project.properties:

```perl
annotation.processing.enabled=true
annotation.processing.enabled.in.editor=false
annotation.processing.processors.list=
annotation.processing.run.all.processors=true
annotation.processing.source.output=${build.generated.sources.dir}/ap-source-output
application.title=ContenedoresChart
application.vendor=Diego
build.classes.dir=${build.dir}/classes
build.classes.excludes=**/*.java,**/*.form
# This directory is removed when the project is cleaned:
build.dir=build
build.generated.dir=${build.dir}/generated
build.generated.sources.dir=${build.dir}/generated-sources
# Only compile against the classpath explicitly listed here:
build.sysclasspath=ignore
build.test.classes.dir=${build.dir}/test/classes
build.test.results.dir=${build.dir}/test/results
compile.on.save=true
compile.on.save.unsupported.javafx=true
# Uncomment to specify the preferred debugger connection transport:
#debug.transport=dt_socket
debug.classpath=\
    ${run.classpath}
debug.test.classpath=\
    ${run.test.classpath}
# This directory is removed when the project is cleaned:
dist.dir=dist
dist.jar=${dist.dir}/ContenedoresChart.jar
dist.javadoc.dir=${dist.dir}/javadoc
endorsed.classpath=
excludes=
file.reference.commons-io-2.4.jar=src\\contenedoreschart\\commons-io-2.4.jar
file.reference.guava-18.0.jar=src\\contenedoreschart\\guava-18.0.jar
file.reference.json-simple-1.1.1.jar=src\\contenedoreschart\\json-simple-1.1.1.jar
includes=**
# Non-JavaFX jar file creation is deactivated in JavaFX 2.0+ projects
jar.archive.disabled=true
jar.compress=false
javac.classpath=\
    ${javafx.classpath.extension}:\
    ${file.reference.commons-io-2.4.jar}:\
    ${file.reference.guava-18.0.jar}:\
    ${file.reference.json-simple-1.1.1.jar}
# Space-separated list of extra javac options
javac.compilerargs=
javac.deprecation=false
javac.processorpath=\
    ${javac.classpath}
javac.source=1.8
javac.target=1.8
javac.test.classpath=\
    ${javac.classpath}:\
    ${build.classes.dir}
javac.test.processorpath=\
    ${javac.test.classpath}
javadoc.additionalparam=
javadoc.author=false
javadoc.encoding=${source.encoding}
javadoc.noindex=false
javadoc.nonavbar=false
javadoc.notree=false
javadoc.private=false
javadoc.splitindex=true
javadoc.use=true
javadoc.version=false
javadoc.windowtitle=
javafx.application.implementation.version=1.0
javafx.binarycss=false
javafx.classpath.extension=\
    ${java.home}/lib/javaws.jar:\
    ${java.home}/lib/deploy.jar:\
    ${java.home}/lib/plugin.jar
javafx.deploy.adddesktopshortcut=false
javafx.deploy.addstartmenushortcut=false
javafx.deploy.allowoffline=true
# If true, application update mode is set to 'background', if false, update mode is set to 'eager'
javafx.deploy.backgroundupdate=false
javafx.deploy.disable.proxy=false
javafx.deploy.embedJNLP=true
javafx.deploy.includeDT=true
javafx.deploy.installpermanently=false
javafx.deploy.permissionselevated=true
# Set true to prevent creation of temporary copy of deployment artifacts before each run (disables concurrent runs)
javafx.disable.concurrent.runs=false
# Set true to enable multiple concurrent runs of the same WebStart or Run-in-Browser project
javafx.enable.concurrent.external.runs=false
# This is a JavaFX project
javafx.enabled=true
javafx.fallback.class=com.javafx.main.NoJavaFXFallback
# Main class for JavaFX
javafx.main.class=contenedoreschart.ContenedoresChart
javafx.preloader.class=
# This project does not use Preloader
javafx.preloader.enabled=false
javafx.preloader.jar.filename=
javafx.preloader.jar.path=
javafx.preloader.project.path=
javafx.preloader.type=none
# Set true for GlassFish only. Rebases manifest classpaths of JARs in lib dir. Not usable with signed JARs.
javafx.rebase.libs=false
javafx.run.height=600
javafx.run.width=800
javafx.signing.blob=false
javafx.signing.enabled=true
javafx.signing.type=self
# Pre-JavaFX 2.0 WebStart is deactivated in JavaFX 2.0+ projects
jnlp.enabled=false
# Main class for Java launcher
main.class=com.javafx.main.Main
# For improved security specify narrower Codebase manifest attribute to prevent RIAs from being repurposed
manifest.custom.codebase=*
# Specify Permissions manifest attribute to override default (choices: sandbox, all-permissions)
manifest.custom.permissions=
manifest.file=manifest.mf
meta.inf.dir=${src.dir}/META-INF
mkdist.disabled=false
native.bundling.enabled=false
platform.active=default_platform
run.classpath=\
    ${dist.jar}:\
    ${javac.classpath}:\
    ${build.classes.dir}
run.test.classpath=\
    ${javac.test.classpath}:\
    ${build.test.classes.dir}
source.encoding=UTF-8
src.dir=src
test.src.dir=test
```

Comment: I've never seen an absolute url being specified in the jar tag. Is that even allowed?

Comment: It was not absolute and I changed it to absolute because i tought the JNLP was the problem, it does work with an absolute url.

Comment: You shouldn't do that. The jar must be part of the classpath. The codebase tag is used for the url. Can you post the full jnlp?

Comment: I added the full JNLP

Comment: I suggest to reference only lib/commons-io-2.4.jar and check that it's in the correct path. ContenedoresChart.jar is obviously loaded, so the lib folder must be on the same path as that jar file on the server.

Comment: Even with lib/commons-io-2.4.jar the " Unable to load resource: http://www.abaxomol.com/dist/lib\commons-io-2.4.jar" error is still there, I guess the problem is that the jar is trying to access commons-io-2.4.jar using "\commons-io-2.4.jar" instead of "/commons-io-2.4.jar"

Comment: Sorry, can't help you there then. But for the others you should post the project.properties as well. I suppose the ":\" is related to the text that comes after the ":\", so it's best to get the full information in order to help you.

Comment: Thanks anyway, I posted the full project.properties.

Answer (score 0):

I had to manually copy all the content in the generated HTML and JNLP into new files, upload those file to the server and remove the old ones and from some reason it worked. A bug maybe? I dont know.

Comment: What do you mean by manually copying the content? How does it make any difference?

Comment: I mean putting two windows side by side and copying the content from the original into a new file character by character. I dont have a single clue why it worked, when I scanned the original file with Janela it showed an error with characters that were not visible maybe there were some invisible character in the auto generated JNLP and by copying it manually the hidden characters were not in the file anymore, thats my best guess.

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete Java cache from Java Control Panel.